# Magnific Popup не подгружается

Tags: jquery

По клику на кнопку `.zoom-link` "magnific" срабатывает, но тут же закрывается.

`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.zoom-link', function() {
  $('#gallery').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    closeBtnInside: true,
    mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true,
      duration: 300,
      opener: function(element) {
        return element.find('img');
      }
    }
  }).magnificPopup('open');
});
```

```html
<div id="gallery">

  <a href="img/portfolio/Layer31.jpg" class="gallery-item mobile">
    <img src="img/portfolio/Layer31.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="gallery-item__hover">
      <div class="get-link"></div>
      <div class="zoom-link"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  ......
</div>
```

Подскажите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть так лучше будет? :

```js
  $('#gallery').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    closeBtnInside: true,
    mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true,
      duration: 300,
      opener: function(element) {
        return element.find('img');
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
body,
#gallery {
  padding: 2rem;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="gallery">

  <a href="http://www.simpsonsfamily.ru/wallpapers/angree-homer.jpg" class="gallery-item mobile">
    <img src="http://www.clubsovetov.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/gomer.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="gallery-item__hover">
      <div class="get-link"></div>
      <div class="zoom-link"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  ......
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Потому как не понятно для чего Вы используете `$(document).on('click', '.zoom-link', function() { ...`

Comment: Как вы предложили, открывается по клику на саму картинку. 
А я хотел сделать чтобы по наведению на картинку показывались кнопки, по клику на одну из них срабатывал бы magnific. Но за ответ спасибо.

Comment: Прислушался к вашему ответу и сделал следующее. 
`
$('.zoom-link').on('click', function(){
    $('#gallery').magnificPopup({
 ..... 
    }).magnificPopup('open');
});
`
Все заработало.